# Using a friend function to access variables

Tags: c++, class, object, operator-overloading, friend-function

I have this piece of a class:

```
class Complex{
friend double Re(const Complex &z);
friend double Im(const Complex &z);
public:
    Complex();
    Complex(const double &, const double &);
    Complex &operator += (const Complex &);
private:
    double real, imag;
};
```

with `+=`, `*=`, `/=` and `-=` defined as members, and `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` as non members, as usual.

The question is, is it okay to implement the operator overloading and member functions in terms of friend functions (using `Re(z)` and `Im(z)` functions), or implement those in terms of private variables (`z.real` and `z.imag`)?

Also, is it okay to define member functions in terms of other members functions or friends, or should they be self-contained? Something like: implement `/=` overload in terms of `*=` and `conjugate()` and `modulus()` functions, or implement it self-contained with private variables?

Comment: In general, it's perfectly OK for one member function to call another. Whether it makes sense to implement division specifically in terms of multiplication and conjugate - that's a problem area question, not the language question. Best addressed to mathematicians with expertise in numerical analysis.

Comment: If definitions of `Re` and `Im` are visible at the point of call and can be inlined, then any decent compiler would generate the same machine code for `z.real` and `Re(z)`. Use whatever syntax you like best.

Comment: thanks, I've been reading a loot about c++ practices, like prefer non-member functions to member and friends etc, and read a lot of arguments about not using friend functions, but in this case seems reasonable, it enhaces the syntax.